# how can i deploy my servlet to a real public server (eatj) from localhost

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

I don't know what I did wrong...so here's the situation.

I created a servlet named User.

```
package user;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;

import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

/**
 * Servlet implementation class User
 */
@WebServlet("/User")
public class User extends HttpServlet {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    /**
     * @see HttpServlet#HttpServlet()
     */
    public User() {
        super();
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    /**
     * @see HttpServlet#doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
     */
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        response.setContentType("text/html); charset=UTF-8");
        PrintWriter writer = response.getWriter();
        writer.print("<html> <body>hello world!!!!!!!!! </body></html>");
        writer.close();
    }

    /**
     * @see HttpServlet#doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
     */
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }

}
```

very simple servlet that does nothing but print hello world. It is working as expected when I tried to run on localhost, but of course I want to run it on an actual server at some point.

so, I found a jsp host at [eatj](http://www.eatj.com/) that offers free trail account for testing purpose. Everything looks very simple. All I did was just right click the project and export as WAR file then upload to eatj, but this time I got 404 error. I'm totally clueless....

I want to know if I need to do anything special to deploy servlet on eatj? 
please help me! thank you soooo much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it is giving http 404 error means your application is not deployed successfully or the URL what you are using is wrong.

Just to try I have a created a new application deployed it on eajt server, its up and running.

Check below is my app url,

http://sandeeppatange.s156.eatj.com/sample-webapp/

Comment: can you please share how exactly you did? or share your WAR file please.  or if you did anything special?

Comment: in my localhost, I had http://localhost:8080/Test/User, so I tried http://ohpoloya.s156.eatj.com/Test/User but got 404...

Comment: Did you restarted the server, once upload war? You need to restart it. follow this: http://s41.eatj.com/index.jsp?url=getting_started.html

Comment: yes i did. i even delete all uploaded files, recreate Tomcat, upload WAR then restart server, but still no hope

Comment: do I need to modify web.xml?

Comment: I dont think so. If its working in your local means should work on any server. Can you please post your complete code.

Comment: the above is already my complete code. I went to "Java Resources" -> "src" folder -> right clicked then picked "New" -> "Servlet". that's how I created this java file.

Comment: then all I did was trying to see if I was able to print hello world.

Comment: I ur servlet remove @WebServlet("/User") and try web.xml configuring this way.. <servlet>
   <servlet-name>test</servlet-name>
   <servlet-class>com.sample.Servlets.UserServlet</servlet-class>
  </servlet>
  
  <servlet-mapping>
   <servlet-name>test</servlet-name>
   <url-pattern>/user</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>

Comment: can you please take a look at my example here? https://www.dropbox.com/s/c3vrdsdqeqpvfbq/Test.war?dl=0

Comment: I tried to comment out @WebServlet("/User") and modify web.xml. i can't even start my localhost now. what did i do wrong??

Comment: I tried with your code only.. Initially I was also getting the 404 error, because I was using the tomcat5 and java6 in eatj. When I changed it to tomcat7 and java7, Its started working. This is by using @WebServlet("/User"), without configuring anything in the web.xml.  http://sandeeppatange.s156.eatj.com/Test/User